# macOS SpriteKit Force Integrated GPU

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I have an application on macOS that uses SpriteKit and SpriteKit Scenes to present snow (for the holidays of course). 
The problem is when this happens macOS forces the dedicated GPU which KILLS battery and doesn't seem to be necessary for this to run well.

My question is if possible, is there any way to force the dedicated GPU in this case? I have tried adding NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching to YES in my Info.plist but it doesn't seem to work... Thank you!

Comment: This comes from apple docs: `Additionally, you must make sure that your application works correctly with multiple GPUs or else the system may continue forcing your application to use the discrete GPU. TN2229 Supporting Multiple GPUs on Mac OS X discusses in detail the required steps that you need to follow. You're highly recommended to check it out.` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1734/_index.html

Comment: Of course the actual link to TN2229 on that page is dead, so here is where you should be going:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2229/_index.html